# Как переписать HashMap с новыми значениями, опираясь на старые?

Tags: java, java-hashmap, hashmap

Поясню)
Есть мапа с кол-вом использования символов в тексте, меня не интересует кол-во, меня интересует последовательность этого кол-ва.
Например:
Дана мапа
А - 37
Б - 64
В - 36
Г - 55
Это то, сколько раз встречаются эти символы в тексте. А мне нужно получить
А - 3
Б - 1
В - 4
Г - 2
Как бы получить очередность частоты использования этих символов

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Берете сет элементов входной мапы, сортируете его по убыванию значений, и перенумеровываете.

Возможное решение, использующее Stream API и итератор `Stream::forEach`, в котором будет меняться входная мапа.

Для перенумерации используется *условно неизменяемый (effectively final)* значение в массиве `int[] x = {1};`.  Его можно заменить атомарным целым `AtomicInteger`.

```java
Map<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<>(
    Map.of("А", 37, "Б", 64, "В", 36, "Г", 55)
);
System.out.println(data);

int[] x = {1};

data.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
    .forEach(e -> data.put(e.getKey(), x[0]++));

System.out.println(data);
```

Вывод:

```
{А=37, Б=64, В=36, Г=55}
{А=3, Б=1, В=4, Г=2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Выносите пары `pair<char, int>` из словаря (map) в массив пар. Сортируете по убыванию по второму элементу пары - числу. Для вашего случая получится `{{'Б', 64},{'Г', 55},{'А', 37},{'В', 36}}` Дальше идете по массиву и во второй элемент пары записываете индекс этой пары. Т.е. получится `{{'Б', 1},{'Г', 2},{'А', 3},{'В', 4}}`. Дальше если хотите - переносите обратно в словарь.